# Swagger ui adds an additional /path in the testing page when behind zuul

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud, swagger-ui, netflix-zuul

I have several microservices behind a spring boot application embedding zuul, let's call it "**gateway**".

Here's my config file:

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    api-login:
      path: /login/**
      url: http://localhost:8070/the-login/
    api-other:
        ...
```

I want to show the documentation for every service of mine in my gateway application so I created the following:

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SwaggerDocumentationController implements SwaggerResourcesProvider{

@Override
public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
    List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<SwaggerResource>();
    resources.add(swaggerResource("login-service", "/api/login/api-docs", "2.0"));
    ...
    return resources;
}

private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location, String version) {
    SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
    swaggerResource.setName(name);
    swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
    swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(version);
    return swaggerResource;
}
 }
```

It works pretty much fine: each time the user goes to **/gateway/api/login** it gets redirected to my microservice, so to **/the-login/**. Also, when the user goes to /gateway/login/swagger-ui.html they can see the documentation.

The problem is that when the user tries an api from the swagger ui documentation page they get:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-05-12T15:35:38.840+0000",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/the-login/the-login/LoginTest"
 }
```

As you can see zuul added one more /the-login to the path!
Is this a swagger-ui bug or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `the-login` as context path in `api-login` service. So when you load gateway service swagger, its add `the-login` into swagger base url as well, like this.
[image: swagger ui]

Thats the reason `the-login` is getting appended twice (one from base-url and one from config). This might be a bug in swagger ui.

A workaround I tried and it worked

**Remove /the-login from application.yml**

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    api-login:
      path: /login/**
      url: http://localhost:8070/
    api-other:
```

Now swagger resource will not load, so need to modify swagger resource path.

**Add the-login in swagger resources**

```
resources.add(swaggerResource("login-service", "/api/login/the-login/api-docs", "2.0"));
```

Comment: does not seem to work...maybe it's the zuul version? What version are you using?

Comment: spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.1.RELEASE https://github.com/hemantsonu20/api-gateway-sample/blob/master/gateway-service/pom.xml

Comment: Updated the answer, plz check

Comment: Mmmm...but doing so will prevent me to call the apis at all as they will not be found...

Comment: I mean, I would have to call my apis using /api/login/the-login/API but this would show some hidden details like the context name and I don't want that...moreover it is a repetition.